# Is there anything as 'sharp corner discontinuity'?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, continuity

My teacher told me if there is a sharp turn in graph, it is called **sharp corner discontinuity**. But when I was solving problems at Khan Academy([www.khanacademy.org](http://www.khanacademy.org)), there I came to know that if the sharp corner has a value, it becomes continuous at that particular point. Is my teacher wrong?[A screenshot of the question I solved at Khan Academy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSoTJ.png)

Comment: A point like that is not a discontinuity. The function has no derivative there, but it is continuous.

Comment: Points like these are also known as a "cusps".

Comment: A cusp is something like $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ at $0.$

Comment: I've seen the French term *point anguleux* used at a point of continuity where both unilateral derivatives exist (finitely or infinitely) and are different. See [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22point+anguleux%22&filter=0). However, I haven't seen the corresponding English term -- *angular point* -- used much, and certainly not as often as I've seen *corner point* used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not discontinuities in the function but discontinuities in its first derivative.